# Shortest way to automatically upgrade all WordPress instaces under document root (>=4.7.x)

Tags: shell-script, cron, software-updates, wordpress

I have a Ubuntu 16.04 Nginx environment with a few minimal WordPress sites (virtually all with up to 5 conventional plugins, 10 pages, 10 images, and a simple contact form to send only textual data).

I daily execute the script `cron_daily.sh` with the following three loops, from `crontab`, to update all WordPress apps under document root. The script uses the [WP-CLI](http://wp-cli.org/) shell extension.

```
for dir in ${drt}/*/; do cd ${dir} && wp plugin update --all --allow-root; done
for dir in ${drt}/*/; do cd ${dir} && wp core update --allow-root; done
for dir in ${drt}/*/; do cd ${dir} && wp theme update --all --allow-root; done
```

<sub>`${drt}` is document root. It was already declared outside permanently, with its file sourced.</sub>

---

I was looking for a way to unite the behavior of these three loops into one segment.

This pattern seems promising, and is based on [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/184844/159710) example:

```
for dir in ${drt}/*/; do
    if pushd ${dir}; then
        wp plugin update --all --allow-root
        wp core update --allow-root
        wp theme update --all --allow-root
        popd
    fi
done
```

Is this the shortest pattern one could use? 
How would you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why three times the same loop instead of one loop like in your example?

At first glance I don't see how this could get any shorter — nor why it should.

If anything, the script could get better (and thus longer) by improving the detection of WordPress (if needed). Also, I'd probably run `wp language core update` as well to make sure translations are up-to-date.

Comment: Thx. Improving the detection of WordPress?

Comment: I now understand you probably meant to `wp core is-installed`.